# How do I create DocumentSnapshots for Firebase Firestore for testing purposes?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am writing an iOS app in swift and I need to test my promise chain. Part of the logic in the app depends on if Firestore returns a valid DocumentSnapshot from a call. If valid doc then go to main screen, else create new user flow.

I can't instantiate a DocumentSnapshot directly or inherit and override it, what else can I do? As a last resort I could just dependency inject something in its place for test but I thought to ask here first.

Anyway I can instantiate a DocumentSnapshot object myself?

Comment: What's wrong with just reading the document from FireStore? Why do you need to instantiate something in code? Have a test path and a real path. The test path doesn't return a valid document and the real one does.

Answer (score 0):

The library `firebase-functions-test` has what you need I think and it is documented in the Unit Testing functions section of the Firebase Documentation here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing#constructing_test_data